# change img src on click

Tags: jquery, image, src

I have searched the forum for one particular issue, yet all the solutions I found do not work for my problem.

I have an image on the left hand side. On the right hand side, I have different words. So, When I click on a particular name, I want the picture to change to whatever picture I have in my image folder. Basically, I want the source of the image to change. Here is the code for my index:

```
<div id="picture_here">
     <img src="images/mtkili.png" id="picture"/>
</div>

<div id="about">
     <div id="mtl">Mtl</div>
</div>

<div id="about_2">
     <div id="contact">SF</div>
</div>
```

and here are two jqueries formulas I tried:

```
$('#mtl').click(function(){
    $('#picture').attr()({
        'src':'images/short.png'
    })          
})
```

and:

```
$('#mtl').click(function(){
   $('#picture').attr('src', 'images/short.png');
});
```

Comment: The first attempt won't work but the second looks fine. What happens with that one?

Comment: yes second attempt should work.

Comment: How does the clicked text determine what image should be shown? And what does 'change to whatever image I have in my image folder' mean, in context?

Comment: The second one works perfectly. http://jsfiddle.net/rhess/ Did you include jQuery?

Comment: David Thomas, I have some pictures in a folder. And so when I click on a description (usually one or two words), the picture on the left hand side changes to a picture found in my images folder.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your second attempt is correct. Here is the working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MEHhs/

So the code should be:

html:

```
<div id="picture_here">
     <img src="http://www.sbtjapan.com/img/FaceBook_img.jpg" id="picture"/>
</div>

<div id="about">
     <div id="mtl">Mtl</div>
</div>

<div id="about_2">
     <div id="contact">SF</div>
</div>​
```

js:

```
$('#mtl').click(function(){
    $('#picture').attr('src', 'http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/41811_170099283015889_1174445894_q.jpg');
    });
```

I've added some existing images found on google.

Comment: Thank you for your input! :D It works nicely. Strangely, yesterday I had the same coding I have now. So I am trying again with my code alongside yours (well, not alongside it, but in a new document), and both codes work, perhaps my two initial documents were corrupted somehow???

Answer (score 4):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ahokax/1/edit)**

- Add a class to all your triggers
- create images called: `mtl.png` and `contact.png`

and use:

```
<div>
     <div class="button" id="mtl">Mtl</div>
</div>
<div>
     <div class="button" id="contact">SF</div>
</div>
```

```
$('.button').click(function(){
   var idToSRC = 'images/'+ this.id +'.png';
   $('#picture').attr('src', idToSRC);
});
```

---

While the above will not be user friendly cause there's some latency in loading new images...
 **A better approach** would be to use a single (so-called) *sprite* image, containing all your desired images, set it as a DIV background image and changing that DIV's "background-position" on click!

## **[USING SPRITES demo 2](http://jsbin.com/ahokax/4/edit)**

Store your desired -left position into a data attribute:

```
<div id="picture"></div>
<div>
     <div class="button" data-bgpos="68" id="mtl">Mtl</div>
</div>
<div>
     <div class="button" data-bgpos="100" id="contact">SF</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#picture{
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  background:url(/images/sprite.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Retrieve that data and move the packgroundPosition:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  var bgpos = $(this).data('bgpos');
  $('#picture').css({backgroundPosition: -bgpos+' 0'})
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have never seen the code "data" before. What is this about exactly?

Comment: @MidevilChaos The data attribute is a new useful HTML5 stuff. read more http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 2):

It all looks good for the second version, make sure you are wrapping your DOM calls in the document ready function, which can be written as...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

Or...

```
$(function() {
    ...
});
```

So you get...

```
$(function() {
    $('#mtl').click(function(){
        $('#picture').attr('src', 'images/short.png');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart. That is very good advice for anyone with the same problem, but who haven't added that particular piece of code. Good input! :)

Comment: Thanks, it was a stab in the dark as the second version looked fine and that was the only thing I could think of that would cause it not to work unexpectedly (and not throw an error)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding event listeners to each link class you can just use it as an inline function on any link

```
function changeurl(theurl){
    $('.myimage').attr('src', theurl);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rabiee3/ftkuub3j/

Answer (score 1):

The second one works fine but you have to use explicit path instead of relative path:

```
$('#mtl').click(function(){
$('#picture').attr('src', '/images/short.png');
});
```