# how to change the src path to an image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, path

The path to an image looks like this:

```
<img src="uploads/image1.jpg">
```

The image is visible when on `index.php` in the same directory as `uploads` is.
But for my admin, i use a subdirectory `admin`. So to view the image, the path now should be

```
<img src="../uploads/image1.jpg">
```

Is it possible to add the `../` before the uploads with jquery? and how can i do that?

I want to make this work for all images in the `uploads` folder!

Comment: @Sheepy YES! Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery function will change all images `src`:

```js
$.each($("img"), function(){$(this).attr("src","../"+$(this).attr("src"));});
console.log($("body").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="uploads/image1.jpg">
<img src="image1.jpg">
<img src="uploads/image9.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this...

```js
$('#image').click(function() {
  $('#picture').attr('src': '../uploads/image1.jpg')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image">
  <img src="uploads/image1.jpg" id="picture" />
</div>
```

see this answer [change img src on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784144/change-img-src-on-click)

Comment: Check your jquery `attr()` syntax

Comment: still its wrong

Comment: check https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp