# Replace image on mouse click using jQuery and Django doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I want to replace an image when it is clicked using jQuery. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
{% load static %}
<div class="col-md-6 image">
    <img class="map" src="{% static 'home/map.png' %}" class="doctors">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.map').click(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "{% static 'home/map2.png' %}");
    });
})
```

I tried the code above and it didn't work. The location of the image and its image format is already correct but when I click the image it only shows a blank picture (the same display as when we write the wrong image format).

I already tried to change the jQuery into this one too

```
$('.map').click(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "home/map2.png");
});
```

but it still didn't work. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Can you try to make your code run like this? https://jsfiddle.net/rabiee3/ftkuub3j/  Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784242/3825777

Comment: Hello so apparently my code works when I change the source with url of images online, thank u for your answer!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution in a runnable stack-snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.map').click(function() {
        var img2 = $(this).attr("data-img2");
        $(this).attr("src", img2);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 image">
       <img class="map" data-img2="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like to avoid JS errors along with liquid code

---

**HTML**

```
{% load static %}
<div class="col-md-6 image">
    <img class="map" data-img2="{% static 'home/map2.png' %}" src="{% static 'home/map.png' %}" class="doctors">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.map').click(function() {
        var img2 = $(this).attr("data-img2");
        $(this).attr("src", img2 );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting that.  I used sample images and a runnable snippet to make it easy to demonstrate visually that this works.